# Linux Bash resize image half the size (linear)

Tags: linux, images

I'm trying to come up with a way of resizing images in a directory by half (longways). 
I have already used:

```
mogrify -resize 50% *
```

It does resize all the image in the file but width and length ways. 
I have a "pseudo" idea for:

```
for images in $picDir; do
    width = images.width()
    height images.height()
    convert -resize $height*$width/2 images
```

I am not sure if that is the correct way to go through a directory and I cannot find an efficent way to get the height and width of a specific file. I would like to also find a way to do this without using Imagemagick and something that is already pre instaled on a ubuntu machine. If that is possible!

Comment: Why not just resize by sqrt(2)/2 ~ 0.7071 (~71%).

Comment: I only want to cut then length in half not both hence why the original piece of code wont suffice.

Comment: Aha. But the `-resize` option requires a "geometry" as argument; I'd expect that something like `100%x50%` (or vice versa) would then work. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have but that doesn't seem to change anything, strangley.

Comment: Works for me. Just tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by resizing only the "length", try one of

```
mogrify -resize 50%x100% *

mogrify -resize 100%x50% *
```

Comment: I kept putting * instead of x. Silly mistake. Thank you